# The ls command shows me the userid instead of username how can I fix this?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to unix scripting, learning it experimenting my own ways.
But then I was trying to list the directory and found numbers like 1000 and 1001.

I google and understood that those are the userid's I verified the same.
But then I wish to display the username for readability on the unix ls command.

Please help me and guide on the same.

Thanks ^_^

**-- Edit_1**

When I type the "ls -al" the out put of that was as mentioned below.

[Image of ls -al output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6J1X.png)

But then in that there were id's like 1000 of the owner and I wanted the name of the user instead of the id.

**--Solution**

I have logged in as root user and used the below command.

sudo chown -R :

And the above solution worked and I am able to see the username instead of userid.

The link to the actual answer is `[this][2]`

Thank you all for the help :)

Comment: What exact command did you run? Was it `ls -l`? Could it have been `ls -n`? What is the output of `type ls`?

Comment: As always it is best to see your question with the command entered and output displayed when you copy and paste your screen into your question.

Comment: Can you post an answer and accept it? Otherwise your question can keep reappearing as unanswered.

Comment: Apologies. Please check I have posted the answer also I included the image in the question but then it appears as a link is that the right way of displaying image ?

Comment: your answer doesn't appear because link #2 is broken...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the username instead of the userid we need to own the directory for that the below is the command which needs super user access.

sudo chown -R *username*:*usergroup* *dirname*

Once you own the dir try ls -al then the result will display your name as owner of the dir instead of userid.

Thank you all for the help and support :)

Answer (score 0):

When you first install Windows Subsystem for Linux there are no user IDs setup. You need to create one first:

- [Add User to Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) Distro in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/128052-add-user-windows-subsystem-linux-wsl-distro-windows-10-a.html)

There are times when User IDs cannot get created properly in which case installing the most recent version of WSL from Microsoft Store is best course of action:

- [WSL / Bash on Windows 10: Creating UNIX user failed, returned error code 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1211201/wsl-bash-on-windows-10-creating-unix-user-failed-returned-error-code-10)